# Moving Master Pages

Tags: custom-masterpage

Now I am new to SharePoint I mostly do programming. Our SharePoint Admin set up a new site on our farm and wanted to reuse the Master page. We moved the master page and a  SharePoint solution associated with it. We activated everything but still get an error. The error points to the solution as not being there but it is and is activated so I cannot understand the issue.

This is the error we receive.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

The custom master page probably embeds a custom control. This requires the web.config to be edited so this new type is allowed on the Web application. Deploying the WSP package to that Web application (from CA) should automatically add the missing entries (`SafeControls`) in the corresponding web.config file.

Comment: Wouldn't the current Webconfig already have it. This is what our SharePoint Admin emailed me with. I’m building a new site for Corpxxx to replace the old one on WSS 2007. xxx.xxx.com/SitePages/Home.aspx I looked at how it was setup on SharePointhub and copied what I could find over to this new site. But when I change the Master Page to the XXX\onexxxmaster_teamAccortion masterpage see error below. I’ve enabled the HorizontalMenu as a site collection feature, I must be missing it somewhere else as well.

Comment: Activating the feature may still be possible, even if the solution was not deployed on that Web application. Deploying the WSP (SharePoint solution) to one Web application will make the feature available for all of them, but the web.config won't be edited for new safe controls on other Web apps.

Comment: OK so we checked the Webconfig file and found that the safe control wasn't listed so we added it. Tried again and still the same error. We are going to reset IIS and see what that does.

Comment: Editing the web.config file already triggers a kind of reset (recompilation). But, anyway: you should not do that manually, but rely on the solution deployment (that will ensure all servers in the farm as in sync + may have other impact).

Comment: So you should not import a Solution from one site to another? It must be deployed instead?

Comment: OK, first of, maybe there's a misunderstanding here: what kind of solution do you have? Is it a "farm WSP" (deployed from the Central Administration) or a "sandbox WSP" (deployed into the site collection solution gallery)?

Comment: It is a farm Solution that we have.

Comment: OK, so, to answer your last question: a farm solution (WSP) is uploaded once in the farm, and then it's "deployed" (i.e. you click the "Deploy" button) per Web application (you may have several Web apps in the farm). If the solution is not deployed into a given Web app, some required `SafeControl` entries may be missing, and you may get the error you have.